# Highcharts lines not being drawn until browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm running into issues while testing Highcharts javascript charting library on one of my pages.

The issue i'm seeing is none of the data is visible until I slightly adjust the browsers size. Before resizing the tooltip does show the points.

First I thought the issue was due to jquery tabs, but that was not the case. I added the fix from Highcharts recommendations. http://www.highcharts.com/studies/jquery-ui-tabs.htm

I tried calling the charts setSize() method after initialization to see if manually resizing would cause the lines to be viable.

Any ideas?

Here how i'm initializing the chart.

```
$(div).ready(function(){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {renderTo: 'some-div', type: 'line'},
        title: {text: 'Title'},
        xAxis: {type: 'text',title: {text: null}},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Usage'}},
        series: [{name:"Series 1", data : [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,2,7] }],
        legend: {enabled: true}
    });
})
```

Comment: The div variable I pass through my setup function, edit removes some of the variables.

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, well I didn't exactly find the problem but found a solution.

Upgrading from version v2.1.6 to the latest (v2.3.5) solved it.

Looking through the [changelog](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog) there were a few references to bug fixes with Jquery 1.7/1.8 compatibility issues possibly the reason.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem where the curves only appear after user-selection of a zoom level, although the tooltips are active from the start.  The issue was conflicts between Highstock JS v1.1.5 and jquery-1.9.1.  Reverting to jquery-1.7.2 resolved the issue, but I imagine that moving to more modern versions of both HighChart and JQuery would be the best solution.

Comment: At the beginning try to update to the newest highstock beacuse its very old version

Comment: @adam Hi I'm also facing same problem but with newer version. Have you any idea why exactly it's happened. Thanks